# Twilio MessagingResponse not working with csharp DLL 5.16.2

Tags: c#, twilio, messaging

I recently upgraded the Twilio C# DLL we've been using to handle SMS messages.  We are now on Twilio.DLL v5.16.2.   I have a webhook set up to call a custom URL on our website.  That part is working, because I can log the Request coming in (message SID and body and all that good stuff).  At the end, we have code to instantiate a MessagingResponse object to send back a confirmation that the message was received.   That's not working anymore.  I don't get a SMS message on my phone nor do I see an Outgoing API record on the SMS logs page when I'm logged into my project on Twilio.com (whereas I do see the test message I've sent to our number as an Incoming message).

There is no error or exception either.

Any idea how to debug/solve this?

```
    string responseTxt = "TESTING:  Got it.  Thanks.";
    var smsResponse = new MessagingResponse();
    var smsMsg = smsResponse.Message(responseTxt);
    response.Write(smsMsg);
```

Comment: I "rolled back" to the version of the Twilio.DLL (and dependent DLLs) that we were using prior to this update (5.6) and everything worked again as expected with no code changes.  So... I'd say there's something in the new DLL or perhaps I missed a bit of documentation about breaking changes...?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not a C# developer, so forgive me if I'm wrong. Also, I don't know what happened with this change.

Anyway, from what I can see, the message body when using the `MessagingResponse`'s `Message` method appears to be a named argument now. Changing your code to the following should work for the latest version of the DLL.

```
var smsMsg = smsResponse.Message(body: responseTxt);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I apologize for the delay.  I am returning to what has become an upgrade "project".  I once again upgraded my Twilio helper library to the latest (v5.25.1) and its dependencies.  But the MessagingResponse is once again no longer working.  I know that my webhook is being called as I'm logging before and after debugging statements.

Comment: Since it's been a while, can you update your question with the latest code that you are using and explain exactly what isn't working right now? Thanks!

Comment: see "answer" below.  Not really answer, but thought my reply was more than a "comment."

Comment: Hey @MargoNoreen, did you try adding a `body` key for the message, as in my answer above? I think that is what has changed over the versions that you are upgrading between.

Comment: I did add it, but it made no difference.  FWIW, the signature of the MessageResponse.Message object did not change between the two versions, so I didn't expect it to make a difference.  Named Parameters exist in v5.6; but the body parameter was first anyway.  So in this case, using or not using that named param didn't matter, as that only applies if your trying to pass parameters "out of order" as it were.  Regardless, I added it for sake of argument.  No change.

Comment: Hi Margo, if you're still having difficulties with this I'd recommend a couple of things. First, try to make a minimal example of this going wrong and see if you can spot where an error is being thrown or something returning some sort of `null` value instead of the XML string. Once you have that example, send it to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to direct your issues to the SDK team. Sorry I've not been able to help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's much to update as the exact same scenario still stands.  But I can reiterate to see if this provides any additional clues.

We have a Twilio SMS service set up.  There is a webhook assigned to our number that maps to an HTTP Handler on an ASP.NET website.  The code in the handler logs in our database the fact that an SMS message was received and various bits of info (from the Request.Form variables supplied by Twilio, From number, body of the message, num of media, etc.).

Then, the code "replies" to the original SMS sender using the MessagingResponse object.  See original code snippet.  Really couldn't be much simpler.

Note, this is and has all been working quite well, using the Twilio c# helper library 5.6.

I upgraded the Twilio library to the latest rev (5.25.1) and its dependencies.  Copied the new DLLs to our dev webserver.  Now the reply message, using the MessagingResponse object, never occurs.  The webhook is still called as I can see the new record in the database logging the message details.  Just no response.  No error, no exception.  Just nothing.

If I rollback to our old version of the Twilio library (and its dependencies, thank goodness for Git!), it works again.